# Automate snapping GeoJSON data on OpenStreetMap with their road XML file?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geojson, xml

I currently have Route data in GTFS that I converted to GeoJSON format and stored in MongoDB. However, even the GTFS provided have still some shapefiles missing therefore a lot are still hovering over blocks and not on the road.

*So I figured out that I could at least automate these lines to snap on the road from the provided XML file from OpenStreetMap. Can this be done in Python or JavaScript?*

Of course not every on load, it would be nice that on my first and only run on that code it would also update the linestring in the database already. Would this be possible?

*possible problem I am anticipating would be the route's direction.

Comment: So you are looking for a solution about "map matching" based on OSM data? ... If yes, you are looking for a map matching software at all, or just a method to do a lot of map matching automatically?

Comment: @stephan75 a lot of map matching automatically. I'll be using it in a web application that constantly adds and edits routes. You might as well call it the web version of a software?